# Save UISwitch state in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I would like to save the state of a UISwitch label with UserDefaults. My code looks like this:

```
func viewDidAppear() {
    mySwitch.setOn(userDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mySwitchValue"), animated: true)
}

func viewWillDesappear() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(mySwitch.isOn, forKey: "mySwitchValue")
}
```

But in the app, when I leave the switch view, and I return in, the UISwitch isn't as I turned it.

Comment: It's unlikely that your `viewWillDesappear` method is called since it is spelled incorrectly. It should be `viewWillDisappear`. If this is a view controller class you would also need `override` for those functions and you should call `super`.

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you check whether the same keyString is being affected somewhere else in the codebase? Or, whether the switch is being affected by somewhere else in the codebase as well?

Comment: Manganese : No, there aren't affected somewhere else..

Comment: rmaddy : I think it's possible but when I try to override, it's said I can't override a function from it's superdlass or something like that

Comment: What class are these methods in? Are they actually being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer to your original query, but an answer to another query in the comment. **Question**: How to set the default state of UISwitch as on, if application is launched for the first time?
Though ideally, it should be asked as another question, given it is incremental, the code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var firstTimeAppLaunch: Bool {
        get {
            // Will return false when the key is not set.
            return userDefaults.bool(forKey: "firstTimeAppLaunch")
        }
        set {}
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        userDefaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "mySwitchValue")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if !firstTimeAppLaunch {
            // This will only be trigger first time the application is launched.
            userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "firstTimeAppLaunch")
            userDefaults.set(true, forKey: "mySwitchValue")
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mySwitch.isOn = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitchValue")
    }

}
```

Note that you could do this within AppDelegate's function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Could add the above code within this as well. Upto you. 
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably, what rmaddy pointed out earlier is the issue. In that case go for spell thingy.

Otherwise, it is possible that setting the value of your switch's state when view is disappearing is not a judicious choice. As when application goes into background other processes are acted upon alongside, and probably setting default is not effected before application closes.

I would generally set such values when I am calling such functions, i.e., in the switch action. As soon as a user changes the switch state, save it in `defaults`, that way when you retrieve it when `viewDidAppear`, it will work.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func switchAction(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        userDefaults.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "mySwitchValue")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mySwitch.isOn = userDefaults.bool(forKey: "mySwitchValue")
    }
}
```

Demo below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! I will try as soon as possible !

Comment: Yeeees I just tried and it work ! Thank you ! Do you know how to set the default state at "On" ? If i delete the app and rebuild, the switcher is Off by default.

Comment: You can simply add a Bool var as "true", and instantiate the state of your UISwitch using the bool var for the first time application is launching (you can use another var to determine if the application is launching for the first time). After first launch, default should be to load the state from UserDefaults.standard

Comment: Please "accept" the relevant answer as the accepted answer, if it worked for you. You can do that by clicking on the tick mark on the left of the accepted answer. Thanks.